# Mediaplayer service not responding

Tags: android, audio, service

The activity is calling for the service to play but it does not start. It should prompt the user for the time and then play for that amount of time. I dont have any errors in the logcat.

```
public class Ship extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
public static final Integer[] TIME_IN_MINUTES = { 30, 45, 60, 180, 360 };
public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
public Handler handler = new Handler();
public Button button2;
public Spinner spinner2;
public PowerManager.WakeLock wl;


// Initialize the activity
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Howaya");

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 wl.acquire();
setContentView(R.layout.ship);
button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
button2.setOnClickListener(this);
spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, TIME_IN_MINUTES);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);

}

// Play the sound and start the timer
private void playSound(int resourceId) {
// Cleanup any previous sound files
cleanup();
// Create a new media player instance and start it


// Create the timer to stop the sound after x number of milliseconds
int selectedTime = TIME_IN_MINUTES[spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition()];
handler.postDelayed(runnable, selectedTime * 60 * 1000);
}

// Handle button callback
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.btn2:
    startService(new Intent(this, Shipservice.class));
    break;
}
}

protected void onDestroy() {

cleanup();
super.onDestroy();
}

// Stop the sound and cleanup the media player
public void cleanup() {
if (mediaPlayer != null) {
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
    mediaPlayer = null;

}
// Cancel any previously running tasks
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}

// Runnable task used by the handler to stop the sound
public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    cleanup();
}
};


@Override
protected void onPause() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onPause();
wl.release();
}

}
```

Here is the service class that should be playing.

```
public class Shipservice extends Service  { 
static final String TAG=Shipservice.class.getSimpleName();
MediaPlayer player;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
return null;
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ocean_ship);
player.setLooping(false);
Log.d(TAG, "onCreate'd");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onDestroy();
Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy'd");
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onStart(intent, startId);
Log.d(TAG, "onStart'd");
}
class ship extends Thread{

@Override
public void run() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.run();
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't write code for playing media file.

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(//path to file);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

write above code in onStartCommand() method in the service class if you want to play media using service. Note - media played by service will continue to play even if your activity is in background until system kills it. See this [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mpandservices) on how to use services. And consider this [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) , how to use mediaplayer.

Comment: I just saw your reply, I am sorry for not responding sooner. I used your code and in the .setDataSource path I put the R.id.sound and it has a red line under the setDataSource that tells me to set my file to a string, but doing that tells me to change it back to an int.

Comment: tell me where is your sound file is stored. I recommend you to store sound file in raw folder.

Comment: try R.raw.sound_file_name Note: filename should be in small letters only

Comment: It is stored in the raw folder. the sound is named ocean_ship so in my path to the file I typed (R.raw.ocean_ship) and it then underlines the setDataSource and tells me to set it to a string. When i do that it the tells me to change it back to an int.

Comment: MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ocean_ship);
mediaPlayer.start();  use this procedure if sound file is stored in raw folder. And the above procedure i posted in the answer is to play sound files whose path is available in the form of Sting or URI

Comment: How can I wrap that into my acivity so that it runs when the button on my activity is pressed

Comment: The sound will play using the method you gave me. My new question is how do I make it stop playing? if the app is clsoed the sound keeps playing and I have no way to stop it

Comment: You have to bind the service and then you can send commands to it.[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) is the link to guide you all about service component and how to send commands to it.